# How to connect GameScene.swift with GameScene.sks correctly?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Since I use a lot of nodes, I have been working with GameScene.sks. The nodes are already placed, but now I want to display them with code. For this I use the following code:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

However, this results in several errors or problems:

- not all nodes in the grey rectangle are displayed (see GameScene.sks)
- there are small gaps between the nodes, although I placed them right next to each other

Furthermore, I wonder how I can connect the nodes with the code so that I can use them in functions, for example

I would be very grateful for any answer.

Comment: Check your GameScene.sks size and orientation compare it with the size of your simulator/device that you are testing the game with. I think this is aspect ratio/size issue. I am 90% sure you are using .aspectFill, try to use .aspectFit and you will see black gaps on the sides meaning your scene is not matching the size of the device you are testing. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is all perfectly clear from the SpriteKit game template in Xcode, so try creating a new project and see for yourself. One such example -

```
// Get label node from scene and store it for use later
self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
```